# How do I add freemarker to my IntelliJ project?

Tags: intellij-idea, freemarker

Im learning how to use freemarker and simply trying to add it to my project.

I couldnt find any online resource on how to do it beside the official documentation mentioning **"No real installation is needed. Simply ensure that freemarker.jar is somewhere where your Java application's class-loader will find it. In web application this usually means putting freemarker.jar into the WEB-INF/lib directory of your web application"**

the errors I'm getting are:

1. The dependecy 'org.freemaker;freemaker:2.3.32' not found
2. cannot resolve symbol freemarker, when tryin to import it.

I tried to:

1. add the maven dependency to my pom.xml
2. add the freemarker.jar to src.main.resources

Comment: I'd recommend invalidating your IntelliJ caches and restarting.  Perhaps it's not finding the JAR in your Maven/Nexus repo.

Comment: @duffymo it worked! been stuck for 2 hours on it! Thank you!

Comment: No JARs belong in src/main/resources.  Maven is the correct way to manage this.

Comment: Glad to help.  IntelliJ has that problem for me from time to time.  A cache reset does it every time.